# Develop private bitbucket app with opencpu

Tags: r, web-applications, bitbucket, opencpu

I have a working R script in bitbucket(private account), is it possible to use openCPU to develop a production app with bitbucket?

I have built a different working open-source github app with openCPU(single-user server).
Just wondering if I can have a private app for business use, preferably working with bitbucket.

P.S. Day 2 in openCPU

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It does not seems that continuous integration is available with bitbucket.
With github it is sure, but only with a public email address.

If you want to deploy it on a private server from a private bickbucket account, my advice is to use git to pull the app each time you modify it.

It is more laborious than continuous integration, but it is not very time consuming either.